# Как изменить текстуру 3D модели по клику?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, three.js

Не получается изменить текстуру 3Д модели по клику в Realtime, не могу найти ответ, что отвечает за перерисовку объекта. Смотрел в справочнике Three.js примеры, не могу все равно понять что и за что отвечает :( Помогите разобраться.
Функция работает, и переменная получает значение новой текстуры, но изменения не происходят.

```js
// Сhange material color
   
          const color_white = { materials: "white" };
          const color_grey  = { materials: "grey"  };
          const color_craft = { materials: "craft" };

          changeColor = function(input) {
            if (input.value === "craft") {
              materials = color_craft.materials;
            } else if (input.value === "grey") {
              materials = color_grey.materials;
            } else if (input.value === "white") {
              materials = color_white.materials;
            }
            console.log(materials);
          };
        // Create Camera
          camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(current_box.perCam, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.25, 20);
          camera.position.x = current_box.posX;
          camera.position.y = current_box.posY;
          camera.position.z = current_box.posZ;
          camera.rotation.y += 1 * (Math.PI/180);
        // Create a Controls 
          controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, container);
          controls.enablePan = false;
          controls.enableZoom = true;
          controls.minDistance = current_box.minDistance;
          controls.maxDistance = current_box.maxDistance;
          controls.update();

        // Object resize
        function resize() {
          camera.aspect = w / h;
          camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
          
          renderer.setSize( w, h );

          animate();
          console.log('element resized: ' + w + 'x' + h);
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

        // Create a Lights 
        const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1.0, 3000 );
              pointLight.position.set( 1500, 1500, 1300 );

        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x999999 ); // soft white light

          scene.add(ambientLight, pointLight, );
          var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {

          if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {

            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            console.log( Math.round( percentComplete, 2 ) + '% downloaded' );

          }
        };
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio);
        container.append( renderer.domElement );

       function loadModel() {

          object.traverse( function ( obj ) {

            if ( obj.isMesh )
                obj.material.map = texture;
                material.needsUpdate = true;
          } );

          object.position.y = 0;
          object.position.x = 0;
          object.position.z = 0;
          
          scene.add( object );
          resize();
          animate();
        }

        var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager( loadModel );

        manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

          console.log( item, loaded, total );

        };
        // Load texture
        var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );
        var texture = textureLoader.load(basePath+'materials/'+materials+'.jpg', function(){
          material.map = texture;
          material.needsUpdate = true;
        });
        
        var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader( manager );
        mtlLoader.load(basePath+models+'.mtl', function(materials) {
  
          materials.preload();

          var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
          loader.load(basePath+models+'.obj', function ( obj ) {
           
            object = obj;
            scene.add(obj);
            scene.updateMatrixWorld(true);

          }, onProgress, onError);
        });
        function onProgress( xhr ) {

          if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {

            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            console.log( 'model ' + Math.round( percentComplete, 2 ) + '% downloaded' );

          }

        }
        function onError() {}
        
        // Render scene
        function animate() {
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что для того, чтобы на модели поменять текстуру - приходится заново перезагружать всю модель с новой текстурой?

Comment: Ну по идее да, если бы "новый" материал хранился бы в куки или локал сторейдж. Просто при загрузке объект уже имеет дефолтные свойства материала. Мне нужно его менять после загрузки. Но получается так ,что переменная принимает новое значение материала, но объект не изменяется, так как требуется его перерисовка. При обновлении страницы объект получит обратно дефолтные свойства.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот такой вариант: загружать текстуры в массив и потом по нажатию на кнопку назначать материалу ту или иную текстуру в свойство `.map`.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button id="tex_0">Texture0</button>
<button id="tex_1" style="left: 100px;">Texture1</button>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js';
import { OBJLoader } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';

var container;

var camera, scene, renderer;

var mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

var object;

init();
animate();


function init() {

  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
  camera.position.z = 250;

  // scene

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xcccccc, 0.4);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
  camera.add(pointLight);
  scene.add(camera);

  // manager

  function loadModel() {

    setTexture(0);

    object.position.y = -95;
    scene.add(object);

  }

  var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager(loadModel);

  manager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total) {

    console.log(item, loaded, total);

  };

  // texture
  var textures = [];

  var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);
  textures.push(
    textureLoader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg'),
    textureLoader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/colors.png')
    );
    
    tex_0.addEventListener("click", function(){setTexture(0);});
    tex_1.addEventListener("click", function(){setTexture(1);});
  function setTexture (texIdx){
    object.traverse(function(child) {

      if (child.isMesh) {
        child.material.map = textures[texIdx];
      }

    });
  }
  // model

  function onProgress(xhr) {

    if (xhr.lengthComputable) {

      var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
      console.log('model ' + Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');

    }

  }

  function onError() {}

  var loader = new OBJLoader(manager);

  loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/models/obj/male02/male02.obj', function(obj) {

    object = obj;

  }, onProgress, onError);

  //

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

  //

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function onWindowResize() {

  windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

  mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX) / 2;
  mouseY = (event.clientY - windowHalfY) / 2;

}

//

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();

}

function render() {

  camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * .05;
  camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * .05;

  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за наглядный пример, всё теперь предельно понятно.

Comment: @Wooo Пожалуйста :) Рад помочь.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а с моделями так же возможно?

Comment: @Wooo А можно как-то вопрос развернуть с подробностями? С какими моделями? Что возможно так же? ) Если что - у нас есть форум: https://discourse.threejs.org/ , правда, англоязычный. Еще дискорд: https://discord.gg/XymnyH - есть на русском языке.

Comment: Я имел ввиду замену 3D модели(.obj) по клику, так же как и с текстурами, без перезагрузки страницы.